# WCF REST: ReadAsDataContract with Twitter Client (Aaron Skonnard)?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am looking for some help with ReadAsDataContract in WCF REST. I found screencast and walthrough from Aaron Skonnard which shows how to ReadAsDataContract.

For some reason I can't seem to find it again. I have found 1 screencast from him but it only shows info about ReadAsXML etc

Is anybody aware of this screencast and where I can locate it?

I believe the example screencast was a demo of a twitter client - but i could be wrong.

I also may have got the person wrong, Aaron Skonnard?

Failing that anybody know of good info / screencast. If i remember correctly you need to add some attributes and specifically clear the CLR namespace or something like that - such a long time ago i can't remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably find the video you're looking for here: 
http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/olt/howtovideos.aspx?category=WCF%20REST

Comment: Hey Aaron, thanks! But it appears to be subscriber only. I seem to remember it was a free video

Comment: Ahh i see with a guest pass there are 2 videos that are available

Comment: Good to see you here.  There are lots and lots of WCF REST questions that go unanswered.